# Solving The Differential Equation $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{at+by+m}{ct+dy+n}$ where $ad=bc$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have solved the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{at+by+m}{ct+dy+n}$ where each of the alphabets $a,b,c,d,m,$ and $n$ is some constant and $ad=bc$ by the following method.

Multiplying the **RHS** of the differential equation by $\frac{d}{d}$, one obtains

$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{adt+bdy+md}{cdt+d^{2}y+nd}$

Because $ad = bc$, the equation is re-expressed as

$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{b(ct+dy)+md}{d(ct+dy)+nd}$

Let $x = ct + dy$

One obtains $\frac{dy}{dt} = \left( \frac{1}{d} \right)\left(\frac{dx}{dt} -c\right)$

The differential equation is re-expressed as

$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{(b+c)x+(md+cn)}{x+n}$

Rearranging the above equation, one obtains

$\left(\frac{x+n}{(b+c)x+(md+cn)}\right)\frac{dx}{dt} = 1$

Multiplying the **LHS** of the above equation by $\frac{\left(\frac{1}{b+c}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{b+c}\right)}$, one obtains

$\left(\frac{1}{b+c}\right)\left(\frac{x+n}{x+\left(\frac{md+cn}{b+c}\right)}\right)\frac{dx}{dt} = 1$

Let $h$ denotes $\left(\frac{md+cn}{b+c}\right)$

$\left(\frac{1}{b+c}\right)\left(\frac{x+n}{x+h}\right)\frac{dx}{dt} = 1$

Integrating both sides of the above differential equation with respect to $t$,

$\left(\frac{1}{b+c}\right)\int \left(\frac{x+n}{x+h}\right)\frac{dx}{dt} dt = \int dt$

One obtains,

$x + (n-h)$**ln**$|x+h| + K = (b+c)t$

where $K$ is an arbitrary constant.

Substituting $x$ as $ct + dy$ and $h$ as $\left(\frac{md+cn}{b+c}\right)$,

$(ct + dy) + (n-\left(\frac{md+cn}{b+c}\right))$**ln**$|(ct + dy)+\left(\frac{md+cn}{b+c}\right)| + K = (b+c)t$

The above equation is my solution to the differential equation.

However, when applying the solution to the differential equation

$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{-t -2y -3}{2t+4y-1}$

each of the terms with $\left(\frac{md+cn}{b+c}\right)$ is undefined.

Is the reason for the case is because my solution to the differential equation is incorrect?

The differential equations are obtained from the book Differential Equations and Their Applications: An Introduction to Applied Mathematics, 4th Edition by Martin Braun on the section 1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obvious that the problem here is that $b+c=0$. To proceed, you implicitly made the assumption where you divide by $b+c$ that $b+c\neq 0$, so any step after that assumption doesn't apply when setting it equal to zero. However, before that step the analysis is sound and in fact you can indeed set it to be zero at the step where you derived

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{(b+c)x+(md+cn)}{x+n}$$

which you can solve (it is separable)

$$\int\frac{x+n}{md+cn}dx=\int dt\iff\frac{x^2+2nx}{2(md+cn)}=t+C~,~C\in \mathbb{R} $$